# The sign of axion $F$ $F$ dual term in Weinberg

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-anomalies, instantons, axion

Related to the earlier question [$\gamma^5$ rotation of chiral fermion in (1) Peskin&Schroeder, (2) Weinberg, or (3) Srednicki](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/618675/42982).

The sign of axion $F$ $F$ dual term in Weinberg (23.6.16) appears to be
$$
-(\frac{\phi}{M}) \epsilon_{uvmn} F_{a}^{uv} F_{a}^{mn}. \tag{23.6.16}
$$

But it appears to be in Weinberg (23.6.17) as
$$
+(\frac{\phi}{M}+\theta) \epsilon_{uvmn} F_{a}^{uv} F_{a}^{mn}. 
\tag{23.6.17}$$

The $-{\phi}F\tilde{F}$ in (23.6.6) changes to be $+{\phi}F\tilde{F}$ in (23.6.7). Are there reasons behind? Or is this just a typo/mistake?

[image]